how do i avoid expanding the hyperlink in email body using shell script
I am required to send an email using shell script.
The body of the email consists of a hyperlink. The email should also have an pdf attachment.
I have tried using mailx and sendmail. Facing the following issue.
With mailx,
   EMAIL_TO_USERS=/tmp/test.email
   touch $EMAIL_TO_USERS
   pdf_to_attach=sample.pdf

   echo " Hello " > $EMAIL_TO_USERS
   echo " This is test url www.domain.com " >> $EMAIL_TO_USERS

   cat $EMAIL_TO_USERS | mailx -a $pdf_to_attach -r sender@email.com -s "Subject" 
  pooja@email.com
  rm $EMAIL_TO_USERS

This works fine with the attachment but the hyperlink gets expanded in the email that i receive.
When i use www.domail.com :

Hence i tried with sendmail
With sendmail,
ATTACH="sample.pdf"
(
 echo "To: pooja@email.com"
 echo "Subject: hello"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo
 echo "<html><b><font size='7'>H</font>ello</b></html>"
 echo "<html><body><a href="www.domain.com">www.example.com</a></body></html>"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"';
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"';
 echo
 base64 sample.pdf
 ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

This works great with the hyperlink but i cant find the attachment.

The attachment is converted to some random text in the email body.
I cant use mutt because its not available in the server i work on.
Please help!

Which software, specifically, is available for the server at hand? Can you name the Linux distro version? (It's not enough to know you have mailx; we need to know which version of mailx to look up which bugs that version is and isn't subject to)

NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.10 (Ootpa)"
This helps?

What does the hyperlink gets expanded mean?

Shoot -- not as much as it would help with a more transparent distro; RHEL package version listings used to be publicly available, but they shut that down a while back, so folks without subscriptions can't easily check them.

@Shawn : The hyperlink doesnt show like how i want it to be on the email. It displays the full hyperlink ( expanded form )

...huh? Attachments aren't hyperlinks (not natively; a client may display them that way, but that's the client's doing, not a part of the message itself). This might be a place where a screenshot would help to clarify.

probably i have to reframe the problem here. Basically i have 2 issues.

www.example.com doesnt show properly when mailx is used
attachment is missing whem sendmail is used


@CharlesDuffy : added a screenshot for the hyperlink issue. www.domail.com is expanded.

Okay, that helps to explain what you're talking about, but it doesn't really explain why it happens (because we don't know how the specific client you're using implements attachments). If you look at the email headers, is the unwanted content explicitly present? Could you amend the relevant subset of the headers into the question (this time as text)?

Including a side-by-side between those headers and the headers representing an email attachment that the same client displays the way you want would be even better.

How does example.com become domail.com ? Is this the same email from your code?

@DiegoTorresMilano The issue remains the same for www.example.com or www.domain.com. Its just an example that i used for testing purpose.

@CharlesDuffy i have added a screenshot of the sendmail too. If you notice, the hyperlink is ok. But the attachment is converted to some random text in the email body.

Right, the latter is completely normal when you don't follow the format for multi-part content.

The URL modification when you use mailx looks like the effect of an external mail filter.  Operating, more likely than not, on the receiver's side.  Substantially all external URLs in e-mails I receive at my work address from any external sender are modified in similar fashion.  That's a security feature implemented by my organization.

@CharlesDuffy how do i correct it?

"Hence i tried with sendmail" ... quoth the sendmail man page: "Sendmail is not intended as a user interface routine".  Putting a script in front makes the usage a little less as a user interface routine, but you're still dealing with a tool that requires a lot more effort from you than would a user-oriented front end, such as mailx.  Note that mailx is probably using sendmail to actually send the mail.

I don't understand why you've emitted Content-Type: … after the HTML element's end-tag - that's syntactically invalid.  Are you trying to create a multipart/mixed body?  If so, you should do so, and pipe that into sendmail.


With mailx,
[...]
This works fine with the attachment but the hyperlink gets expanded in
the email that i receive.

It looks like mailx is working fine altogether.  The hyperlink mangling you show appears to be the effect of the URL Defense service.  That is normally engaged at an organization's mail gateway to modify external URLs in incoming e-mails to point at a realtime URL filtering server.  This is aimed at protecting recipients from attempts at phishing and fraud.  Very likely, neither mailx nor anything else on your machine is doing that.
It's unclear why you are not seeing the same when you use sendmail directly, but surely that's related more to differences in the message than to the direct use of sendmail.  For example, your mailx sample appears to show the mangled URL having been dumped into the body of a plain text e-mail message, whereas the sendmail sample shows the unmangled URL as the text of a hyperlink in an HTML (sort of) email body.  I wouldn't be surprised to find that in the latter case, the link target had been mangled, but it's impossible to tell from the question.
I'm having trouble finding documentation published by URL Defense itself, but you may find this third-party (UW-Madison) FAQ interesting: https://kb.wisc.edu/132654.

As an aside -- this is why I asked the OP to find an email with an attachment that didn't have this undesired effect, show its headers (comparing them to the headers produced by mailx), and show how their client displays it.
